# React Text Input Losing Focus After Each Keypress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, components, render

When I type, it closes the input. I've tried using autofocus, but it only works on screens with just one input.

**Solved:** after numerous searches going on several forums I simply changed these two attributes:

From this

```
 value={defaultValue}
 onChange={onChange}
```

To this

```
  defaultValue={defaultValue}
  onBlur={onChange}
```

**Component: Input**

```
export default function InputForm({
  label,
  helperText,
  onChange,
  defaultValue,
  type,
  margin,
  disabled,
  key,
}) {
  const CssTextField = styled(TextField)({
    '& label.Mui-focused': {
      color: '#000',
      fontSize: 28,
      fontFamily: 'Inter',
      fontStyle: 'normal',
      fontWeight: '900',
    },
    '& label': {
      fontFamily: 'Inter',
      fontStyle: 'normal',
      fontWeight: '900',
      paddingTop: 20,
      zIndex: 1,
      marginLeft: 12,
    },
    '& .MuiInputLabel-root': {
      color: '#000',
      fontSize: 24,
    },

    '& .MuiInput-underline:after': {
      borderColor: '#000',
    },
    '& .MuiInputBase-input': {
      fontSize: 20,
      fontFamily: 'Inter',
      fontWeight: '900',
      fontStyle: 'normal',
      marginTop: 20,
      color: '#575757',
    },
  });
  return (
    <>
      <CssTextField
        label={label}
        variant="standard"
        size="normal"
        fullWidth
        type={type}
        helperText={helperText}
        value={defaultValue}
        onChange={onChange}
        margin={margin}
        disabled={disabled}
      />
    </>
  );
```

**Import Input**

```
   <main className="container">
        <img src={logo} alt="logo" className="logo" />
        <div className="content-box">
          <Container>
            <h1 className="login-title">ENTRAR</h1>
            <Stack direction="column" spacing={2}>
              <div className="input-container">
                <InputForm
                  label={'NOME DE USUÁRIO'}
                  defaultValue={email}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setEmail(e.target.value);
                  }}
                />
```

I didn't try many solutions, because I couldn't find other similar ones and the ones they had were somewhat distant from what I did, as said above, I just tried autoFocus but it's a bad solution and it only works on pages and only one input

Comment: Can you make an example here? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new